# Passing variables from classes to main class

Tags: python, class, oop

I am trying to pass the data_lst up to Class:'Paper''s function: 'save'  such that I can print it from there. The structure is fixed and I am not allowed to used global variables.
How do i get around this?

```
class Paper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add_page(self, **kwargs):
        self.p = 1
        self.pp = 5

        page = Page(self.p, self.pp, paper=self)
        return page

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        #This is where i want to print the data from get_data
        print('final price =', data_lst)

class Page:
    def __init__(self, p, pp, paper=False):
        self.paper = paper
        self.p = p
        self.pp = pp
        assert paper

    def add_fig(self):
        fig = Figure(p=self.p, pp=self.pp)
        return fig


class Figure:
    def __init__(self, p=0, pp=0):
        self.p = p
        self.pp = pp

        data_lst = self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):
        ### get some data in a list
        data_lst = [self.p for x in range(self.pp)]
        return data_lst


paper = Paper()
page1 = paper.add_page()
page1.add_fig()

#paper.save() this call needs to print the data
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a little. This is just a suggestion.

I changed the fact that the page is returned when calling the add_page method. Instead I store it in the Paper object. Same for the figure.

```py
class Paper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.page = None

    def add_page(self):
        p = 1
        pp = 5

        self.page = Page(p, pp, paper=self)

    def save(self):
        #This is where i want to print the data from get_data
        print(f"final price ={the_paper.page.fig.data_lst}")

class Page:
    def __init__(self, p, pp, paper):
        self.paper = paper
        self.p = p
        self.pp = pp
        self.fig = None

    def add_fig(self):
        self.fig = Figure(p=self.p, pp=self.pp)


class Figure:
    def __init__(self, p=0, pp=0):
        self.p = p
        self.pp = pp

        self.data_lst = self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):
        ### get some data in a list
        data_lst = [self.p for x in range(self.pp)]
        return data_lst


the_paper = Paper()
the_paper.add_page()
the_paper.page.add_fig()
the_paper.save()
```

NB: I removed assert for paper, since assert is not necessarily executed in production context. If you consider that paper is mandatory, then it is better to have remove its default value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `paper.save(data_lst=...)` or change save signature to allow data_lst as a positional argument `def save(self, data_lst, **kwargs):`